# How to set capabilities for a file while sharing with someone using Google drive API V3?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to set capabilities like `canDownload = false, canCopy = false` while sharing a Google drive file with someone using Google API V3.

Right now I'm setting multiple permissions for that file and permissions are working fine but capabilities are not setting.

Here is the code for setting permissions and capabilities :

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=client_secret.json');
     $client = new Google_Client();
     $client->setApplicationName('xyz');
     $client->setAccessType("offline");    
     $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
     $client->setSubject('abc@xyz.com');
     $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
     $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
     $optParams = array('sendNotificationEmail'=> false);
     $capabilities = array('canDownload' => false, 'canCopy' => false );

     $permissiondata =insertPermissionview($service,$request['file_google_id'],$optParams, $capabilities, $request['email_id'],'user','reader');

     $newPermissiondata = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
     $newPermissiondata->setExpirationTime($request['permission_expires_on'].'T10:00:00-05:30');
     $newPermissiondata->setRole('reader');
     $permissiondatavalue=$service->permissions->update($request['file_google_id'],$permissiondata['id'],$newPermissiondata);
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files

So, basically my question is how can I disable download, copy, print option for a reader with whom I've shared my google drive file using drive API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation for a [fileresource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource)  You will notice that neither of those fields are writable. So doing a [file.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) and setting those fields is going to have no effect.  I dont think you can set them when the file is created either as it would make sense that you can download and copy it if you are creating it.  These fields are more then likely for googles internal use.

[image]

[image]

a [permission resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource) just lets you set if the user has access to the file not what they can do with it.

Comment: Can I set these capabilities while uploading a file ? In this case writer of that file will also not get permission to download or copy that file but in some sense my problem will get solve.

Comment: I doubt you can set them when uploading the file either.  Google drive API permissions are very limited.   I have never heard of giving someone write access but them not being able to download the file

Comment: I'm using  "copyRequiresWriterPermission": true  which is a writable parameter and it is working also. Right now I'm using this via Google's interface (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update), I want to get this using API.

Comment: Actually you are trying to set the wrong parameters then try $capabilities = array('copyRequiresWriterPermission' => true);

Comment: I think copyREquireWriterPermission parameter is not a part of capabilities array. Right now it is working using Google's interface  (developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update),  but is it possible to pass this parameter pragmatically ?

Comment: How can i set it so that anyone can download the file.